# When using jqGrid's setFrozenColumns and filterToolbar together, columns disappear

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using the filter row and frozen columns feature at the same time and they seem to be in conflict. Here is a visual of the problem:

Before (on refresh):

```
col1 (frozen) | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6

filter row    
search term   |     |     |     | 

data          | data | data | data| data| data

data          | data | data | data| data| data

data          | data | data | data| data| data

data          | data | data | data| data| data

data          | data | data | data| data| data

data          | data | data | data| data| data
```

But after entering a filter

```
col1 (frozen)  |||||||

filter row 
new search term||||||| 

data           |||||||

data           |||||||

data           |||||||

data           |||||||

data           |||||||

data           |||||||
```

The lines `||||||` represent the columns "sandwiched" together - their data and widths have disappeared.

The 2 lines of code that seem to be in conflict are :

```
loadComplete: function () {

  $.getScript('<%=Url.Content("~/Names/PopulateFilterBar/")%>');

  jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns'); 

},
```

The first statement is a call to a function in the MVC controller that gnerates the the following:

```
 jQuery("[id=gs_Name]").val("company"); }
```

If I remove the first command, the 2nd works perfectly well but I lose the appearance of the filter words on a refresh. If I remove the 2nd, I lose the frozen column feature.

Has anyone seen this error?

Furthermore, I notice that the selection of rows seems to not always work when columns are frozen. I have abondoned the frozen column feature until I can resolve this problem.

I am using jqGrid, all newest versions of jQuery, in VS2010 ASP.NET, .NET 4, MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer: It was suggested that I make all calls to update the grid only "once". Originally, I was using the LoadComplete method to update the grid, this was unnecessarily calling functions on *every* refresh. I have therefore changed my code to remove loadComplete(). Please see new code below.

I have also changed the methodology for populating the filter bar - this is now done entirely at the javascript level and only once.

However, I am unfortuantely still experiencing the nasty behaviour as outlined above. Please if anyone has seen this, much appreciated your response.

updated code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        <%= Html.ToJsColumnNames("dynamicGridDataColumnNames", Model.GridColumns ) %>
        <%= Html.ToJsColumns("dynamicGridDataColumns", Model.GridColumns, "" ) %>
        <%= Html.ToJsShowHideColums("dynamicGridDataShowHideColumns", Model.GridColumns) %>
        <%= Html.ToJsGetCurrentFilters("dynamicGridDataCurrentFilters") %>

        document.title = "CLEAR Masterlist";

        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '<%=Url.Action("DynamicGridData")%>',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: dynamicGridDataColumnNames,
            colModel: dynamicGridDataColumns,
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            pagerpos: 'center',
            rowNum: 100,
            rowList: [100, 100000000],
            sortname: "Name",
            sortorder: "asc",
            height: 600,
            width: 1235,
            loadui: "block",
            shrinkToFit: false,
            multiselect: true,
            multiboxonly: false,
            caption: 'List of Names'
        });

        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
            del: false, add: false, edit: false, search: false, refresh: false,
            view: false, height: 250, jqModal: false, closeOnEscape: true
        });

        $("option[value=100000000]").text('All');

        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { autosearch: true, searchOnEnter: true, stringResult: true
        });

        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');

        var fdiv = jQuery("#list").fhDiv;
        var cf = dynamicGridDataCurrentFilters.split("&&");
        for (var x = 0; x < cf.length; x++) {
            var f = cf[x].split('~');
            if (f.length > 1) {
                var fld = "[id=gs_" + f[0] + "]";
                jQuery(fld, fdiv).val(f[1]);
            }
        }

    });

</script>
```